# How to deactivate/disable a fancytree node?

Tags: jquery, fancytree

I am using fancytree to render a directory, and when the user selects a node in the fancytree, I want to deactivate it.  I've been  searching through the apis and came across setActive(false) which I thought would do the trick. But it doesn't work.  In fact, the user can still select the node, expand, etc...

```
node.setActive() // not working
```

Does anyone the correct way to disable a node in fancytree?

Answer (score 2):

In Fancytree there is one (or no) node active. A node may become active when clicked by the user, using keyboard, or using the setActive() API.

See here for an overview of different statuses: https://github.com/mar10/fancytree/wiki/FAQ

This has nothing to do with a 'disabled' property. There is no API to support that directly, but you could return false in the 'click', 'expand', ... event handlers to prevent default behavior.